# ionic 5 and Odoo connection got error on handling json response

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, odoo, ionic5, json-rpc

I am trying to connect odoo and ionic 5 using api interface. Below is my Odoo controller:

```
 @http.route('/ionicon/authenpost',type="json",csrf=False,cors="*", auth="public",website=False, method=['POST'])
    def authenPost(self, login,pwd,base_location=None):
        
        env = request.env(context=dict(request.env.context, show_address=False, no_tag_br=True))
        db = env.cr.dbname
        request.session.authenticate(db,login,pwd)
        return request.env['ir.http'].session_info()
```

Deployment is ok and already tested with Postman. The response is ok as well.

But when I tried to call with ionic 5 android app, I got the following error:

```
{"status":400,"url":"http://172.20.10.3:8069/ionicon/authenpost","headers":{"date":"Mon, 18 Jan 2021 17:01:05 GMT","content-length":"308","server":"Werkzeug/0.16.1 Python/3.8.2","x-android-selected-protocol":"http/1.0","x-android-response-source":"NETWORK 400","x-android-received-millis":"1610989264019","x-android-sent-millis":"1610989263965","content-type":"text/html"},"error":"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN\">\n<title>400 Bad Request</title>\n<h1>Bad Request</h1>\n<p>&lt;function ionic_conController.authenPost at 0x7fc9687620d0&gt;, /ionicon/authenpost: Function declared as capable of handling request of type 'json' but called with a request of type 'http'</p>\n"}
```

Actually I already pass 'application/json' header. Please see the below code:

```
 this.http.sendRequest("http://172.20.10.3:8069/ionicon/authenpost", { 
  method: 'post',
  responseType: 'json',
  data:{ 'jsonrpc':'2.0', 'params' : { 'login':'testuser@sample.com', 'pwd':'testabc' }},
  headers: {
    accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}}).then(data=>{
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
}).catch(err =>{
  console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

I am using

```
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';
```

it did work with HTTPClient, below is my working code.

```
const httpHeader_ = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    };

    let config ={ headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json') };

    this.httpCli.post("http://172.20.10.3:8069/ionicon/authenpost",
    {jsonrpc : "2.0", params : { 'login':'sampleuser@test.com', 'pwd':'password123' } },
    config).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    },err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

I would like to know how can I get with HTTP?

Where can I put content-type ?

Best Rgds,
jm

Comment: Do you have the same error using the regular `HttpClient` from Angular ?

Comment: yes it did work with HTTPClient const httpHeader_ = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    };

    let config ={ headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json') };

    this.httpCli.post("http://172.20.10.3:8069/ionicon/authenpost",
    {jsonrpc : "2.0", params : { 'login':'sampleuser@gmail.com', 'pwd':'pwd123' } },
    config).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    },err => {
      console.log(err);
    });